# how to edit a website in wordpress using css, php and javascript

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a website in wordpress using css, PHP and javascript and I'm trying to change the background, but whenever I change the image in css it doesn't shows it in the website, and I can't find the HTML file in wordpress to change also the Background Image from there.

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: Your Question is not clear, please make it clear. This could be happen by cache issue , css priority issue. Better use `background-image:url('image-link-here') !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clear, try adding !important with your css selector.

`background-image:url("") !important;`

Comment: what I mean is whenever I change the BG in CSS it doesn't show it, do I have change in somewhere else?,  and I can't find the HTML file in WordPress!

Comment: please show your css code or give your site link for so as to know where the problem is mainly occuring